# Getting an error Remote Server is Forbidden(403)

Tags: abbyy

I am getting forbidden error even though the entire code is correct. Can Anyone look in to this.
Thanks in advanceenter image d[Forbiden error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbzip.png)escription here

Answer (score 0):

You've got to specify Credentials as it's shown in the code sample (comes with the software).